# Best Practices for Managing Complex Addon Registration in Blender 3D

Tags: python, scripting

Hello Blender addon developers,

I'm working on a complex Blender addon that has multiple components like panels, operators, properties, and more. As the addon has grown, I've found that managing the registration process has become increasingly challenging.

Current Approach:
I initially tried to pack everything into one **init**.py file, but it quickly became cluttered. To manage this, I've started using multiple **init**.py files that get registered hierarchically. The registration order is determined by the main **init**.py and the **init** tree in the folders and their subfolders.

Alternative Approaches:
I've noticed that some addons use additional register.py files and abstract the registration process in more intricate patterns. For example, I found an addon on the marketplace that uses a modular approach:

```
from .utilities.register import module_register_factory

base_modules = ["base"]
core_modules = [
    "handlers",
    "model",
    "operators",
    "gizmos",
    "keymaps",
    "workspacetools",
    "UI",
    "draw_handler",
    "registration_delayed",
]

register_base, unregister_base = module_register_factory(__package__, base_modules)
register_full, unregister_full = module_register_factory(__package__, core_modules)
```

Questions:

1. Are there best practices for dividing and managing the registration process in complex Blender addons?
2. Is the modular approach I found a commonly used pattern, or is it more of a "make it up as you go" situation?
3. If you know of any good patterns for organizing registration, could you provide a detailed description or example?

I'm looking for insights and best practices to make the registration process more manageable as the addon grows. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here work for or have any association with the Blender Foundation. Your question is off-topic here as any answers are likely to be be opinion-based. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Not sure there is a "best practice", in the sense that there are plenty of ways to do it and the documentation doesn't tell much about it. But you can look up other addons to see how they do it. I.E. [amaranth toolset](https://github.com/venomgfx/amaranth).

Comment: The question is nor necessarily off topic here, though Blender developers don't come here often, and you are most likely to get answers by other scripters and addon authors here, rather than official developers. If those don't suffice, contacting official developers is probably best done through dev chat or developer forums